# Cant find field in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, field

I am currently working on a scala/spark homework project ibn which I am to read-in a csv file containing a few thousand movie reviews as a dataframe. I am then to analyze these reviews and train a model to detect whether a review is positive or negative. I will be training these models using TF-IDF and Word2Vec. The issue I am having is that the code I have written so far does not find the specified header field named "word" which is output by a regex tokenizer. My code is written below, as well as the console output.

I thank you for your help and appreciate any pointers to how I might do this correctly/better than what I am doing now.

```
import org.apache.spark._
//import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.io._
import scala.io._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import org.apache.spark.{Partition, SparkContext, TaskContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{RegexTokenizer, Tokenizer}

/*
DONE: step 1: loop through all the positive / negative reviews and label each (1 = Positive, 2 = Negative)
        during the loop, place the text that is read as a string into a DF.
step 2: check which words are common among different labels and text with each other (possibly remove stop words)
        this will satisfy the TF-IDF requirement
step 3: convert text into vectors and perform regression on the values
step 4: compare accuracy using the actual data (data for the above was using the test folder data)
*/

object Machine {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Movie Review Manager").getOrCreate()
    println("Reading data...")
    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("movie_data.csv")
    val regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("review").setOutputCol("word").setPattern("\\s")
    val remover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("word").setOutputCol("feature")
    df.show()
    regexTokenizer.transform(df).show(false)
    df.collect()
    remover.transform(df).show(false)
    df.show()
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

And here is the console output:

```
Exception in thread "main" 2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 125
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "word" does not exist.2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 118

2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 116
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 102

2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 110
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:267)2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  ContextCleaner:54 - Cleaned accumulator 103

        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.transformSchema(StopWordsRemover.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.transform(StopWordsRemover.scala:91)
        at Machine$.main(movieProgram.scala:44)
        at Machine.main(movieProgram.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
2018-03-13 03:41:28 INFO  AbstractConnector:318 - Stopped Spark@3abfc4ed{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
```

Comment: Do you get this error even when reading a CSV with one data-line?

Comment: @JeroenHeier it shouldn’t matter.....I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to store the transformation of `new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("review").setOutputCol("word").setPattern("\\s")` to be used for `new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("word").setOutputCol("feature")`

As you missed to save the *regex tokenizer algorithm applied dataframe* to be used for *stop word remover algorithm* and used **the original `df` dataframe (where `word` column is not present)** you had the error stating

> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "word" does not exist...

Correct way is to do as below

```
object Machine {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Movie Review Manager").getOrCreate()
    println("Reading data...")
    val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("movie_data.csv")
    val regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("review").setOutputCol("word").setPattern("\\s")
    val remover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("word").setOutputCol("feature")
    df.show(false)   //original dataframe
    val tokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(df)
    tokenized.show(false)     //tokenized dataframe
    val removed = remover.transform(tokenized)
    removed.show(false)     //stopwords removed dataframe
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly the fix I needed!